# Which are the possible reasons for an arp request that is not being solved/answered?

Tags: cisco, arp, tcpdump, arptables

This weekend I was testing a new data link connection from a service provider, and I went through some address resolutions problems.

I tested reachability to hosts at the far end using a laptop on my side with some network parameters provided by the ISP.

Then, when I configured it on an available NIC on my UTM, the same hosts were not reachable. After confirming my routing configuration was seted up correctly, I started sniffing with `tcpdump` and find out that my linux UTM's ARP requests (`arp who-has`) for the first hop at the other side were not getting an answer. So an `<incomplete>` entry for it's ip address was created at my UTM's ARP table.

As a temporal workaround I added a permanent entry to my UTM's ARP table through `arp -a`.

I did found out that the host not answering my arp requests is an Cisco router (`Cisco 7600 router (IOS 12.2)` according to nmap OS detection feature).
What can be the root cause of this problem?

- Some sort of ACL configuration in the router's ARP? (My laptop did get the ARP resolution)
- Some `arp_filter` not allowing to reply to addresses from other subnets / NAT Required?
- A temporal entry for my laptop on the router's ARP table and spoofing protection activated when I configured the same address on my UTM?.
- A malformed ARP request? (I am not having this issue with my other data links on the same UTM)
- A "not-understandable" ARP answer sent to my UTM?
- Any other?

The netmask for the data link is `/30` so there are only two hosts able to reply the arp request (my UTM and the router)

### UPDATE:

Reply from my ISP:

> We do have security policies applied, but at MAC address level, for
>   the case of the access port (Gi7/3) we have a maximum of 10 Mac
>   allowing traffic for that port, and the log has registered 4 entries
>   to this date, thus ensuring that security action (Restrict) has not
>   yet been activated.

I did upgraded my UTM's hardware in order to get more NICs available. In this upgrade a MAC address change for my NIC receiving the data-link was involved but the behavior was the same, without a static arp entry, I am not able to send packets to the cisco router.

Answer (score 1):

(this should be moved to https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/)

There is no "not understandable" ARP, if your linux-box does not get any answers on arp-requests, your network-config is correct (IP, netmask) and ethernet works (interface is UP).

So there is no possible way to say anything about the cause w/o access to the cisco-device. Some possible causes:

- somehow *wrong* network-config
- static arp-entry
- firewalling/filtering/...